# Concatenate Pandas dataframes with different set of columns

Tags: python, pandas

df1 has columns A, B, C, D, E

df2 has columns A, B, D

How to concatenate them in order to have a resulting dataframe that has rows of df1 and df2, values of A, B and D will be extended from df2 on df1, and columns C and E will be filled with NaN because df2 has no data for them?

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called concat

```
pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

The input must be a iterable, so put them into a list ;)

Comment: It worked. The trick was to put them into a list, it doesn't work as expected without it.